# How to fill in the blanks with calc function?

Tags: html, css, calc

I am trying to fill in the blanks in a div with calc. I fill the first div with 2/3 but 1/2 should be filled with red. Now the red bar will position below the blue one. What do I wrong with the calculation?

See it in action: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqxVeq

```
    .box {
  width: 66.666%;
  width: calc( 100% * 2/3);
  height: 80px;
  background: #09F;
}
.twee {
  background: red;
  height: 80px;
    width: calc( 100% * 2/3 - 1/3);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Foreword

As Quentin mentioned,

> Basic maths. `*` has higher precedence than `-`.

So you need to use `width: calc( 100% * (2/3 - 1/3));` code.

### Problem

`div`s are ill-positioned.

### Solution

Inner `div`s should have `position: absolute;` and outer `div` should have `position: absolute`.
Inner `div`s will be placed relative to outer `div` and thus, blanks will not occur.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var box = document.querySelector('#container .box');
    box.innerText = getComputedStyle( box ).width
}
```

```css
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #444;
    
    position:relative;
}

.box {
    width: 66.666%;
    width: calc( 100% * 2/3);
    height: 80px;
    background: #09F;
    
    position:absolute;
}
.twee {
    background: red;
    height: 80px;
    width: calc( 100% * (2/3 - 1/3));
    
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="twee"></div>
</div>
```

### Appendix

If you wish the red `div` to pass to the right, then add `right:0` to it.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var box = document.querySelector('#container .box');
    box.innerText = getComputedStyle( box ).width
}
```

```css
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #444;
    
    position:relative;
}

.box {
    width: 66.666%;
    width: calc( 100% * 2/3);
    height: 80px;
    background: #09F;
    
    position:absolute;
}
.twee {
    background: red;
    height: 80px;
    width: calc( 100% * (2/3 - 1/3));
    
    position:absolute;
    right:0
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="twee"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Two problems.

First: Basic maths. `*` has higher precedence than `-`. You need parens to force your subtraction to take place first.

```
width: calc( 100% * (2/3 - 1/3) );
```

Second: Div elements are, by default, `display: block` so will start new lines anyway. You need `display: inline-block` or something similar.

Third: Rounding problems. When percentages of pixels aren't integer values, you end up with rounding and after rounding the total can be more than 100% and wrapping comes back.

I'd just use Flexbox for this instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change width of '.twee'

```
.twee {width: calc( 100% * 1/3);}
```

Add this css in your style

```
#container, .box, .twee {float:left}
```